# Run the same ADB Shell script on multiple emulators running simultaneously

Tags: android, automated-tests, adb, android-popupwindow, android-immersive

While running automated UI tests with **multiple** workers I would like to execute the following script:

```
    beforeAll(async () => {
    if (device.getPlatform() === 'android') {
      console.log('*** disable android system popups ***')
      execSync(
        'adb shell settings put secure immersive_mode_confirmations confirmed'
      )
    }
    await device.launchApp()
  })
```

This will not work since the shell does not know which emulator to target.

```
Command failed: adb shell settings put secure immersive_mode_confirmations confirmed
adb: more than one device/emulator
```

Is there a way to simply target all the emulator instances at once with the same command? OR can I somehow access the `adb devices` list with JS and maybe map the command to each instance?